# Error while generating Model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got the following error while generating a Model in ASP.Net:

> *MvcApplication1.Models.Department: : EntityType 'Department' has no key defined. Define the key for the EntityType.*
>   *department: EntityType: EntitySet 'department' is based on type 'Department' that has no keys define.*

Here's a screenshot with more details:

[image]

I added the primary key to the Department table:

```
{    
    [Table("department")]
    public class Department
    {
        public int dept id { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [`[key]` annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx#Key) to your `deptid` field:

```
{    
    [Table("department")]
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int deptid { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 department table. ' {

[Table("department")]
public class Department
{
   [Key]
    public int dept id { get; set; }
    public string department { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
}`
```

Add key attribute, refer [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change `public int deptid` to either `public int Id` or `public int DepartmentId`. This is a built-in EF convention, and if you use this syntax, you don't need the `[Key]` attribute.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: This is the question here I believe, how to make a column which has name other than id as primary key in database first approach. Changing column name may not be appropriate

Comment: The OP doesn't mention any limitations with changing the column name and as such, I just wanted to make him aware of this option. If he cannot change the column name, then your answer is the way to go.